# Slow MYSQL Queries, need help understanding indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

For the purposes of this post I've simplified my problem down to it's purest form.
I have 3 tables: games, games_tags and games_tags_map

Here's what I do if I want to get a table of tags for each game:

```
SELECT `games_tags_map`.`game_id` as 'game_id', GROUP_CONCAT(`games_tags_map`.`tag_id`) as 'tags'
FROM `games_tags_map`
LEFT JOIN `games_tags` on `games_tags`.id = `games_tags_map`.`tag_id`
GROUP BY `games_tags_map`.game_id
```

It takes ~1ms

```
SELECT `games`.`id` AS 'id' from `games`
```

This takes <1ms.

However, when I try and join both of these:

```
SELECT `games`.`id` AS 'id',
t.`tags` as `tags`
FROM `games`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `games_tags_map`.`game_id` as 'game_id', GROUP_CONCAT(`games_tags_map`.`tag_id`) as 'tags'
    FROM `games_tags_map`
    LEFT JOIN `games_tags` on `games_tags`.id = `games_tags_map`.`tag_id`
    GROUP BY `games_tags_map`.game_id
) t ON t.`game_id`=`games`.`id`
```

It takes ~100ms

However, when I do the equivalent query:

```
SELECT `games`.`id` AS 'id',
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `games_tags`.`tag`) AS 'tags'
FROM `games`
LEFT JOIN `games_tags_map` ON `games`.`id` = `games_tags_map`.`game_id`
LEFT JOIN `games_tags` ON `games_tags`.`id` = `games_tags_map`.`tag_id`
WHERE `games`.`active`=1
GROUP BY `games`.`id`
```

It takes 2ms...
But, when I need to order it by anything other than the primary column (id), it takes ~80ms

Just to clarify, this is a very simplfied version of my actual database which is experiencing much longer loading times and causing problems for my website, but it's in queries like these where the problem lies.

There is clearly a flaw in the way my database is set up for such hugely different loading times. I've tried adding more indexes but it hasn't helped.
On the table 'games' I have the primary index 'id'
On the table 'games_authors_map' a primary index consisting of 'game_id' and 'author_id'

I know there's a problem but I can't fix it and I don't understand why.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a join to all the game tags table (which in itself is ok), why not add an aggregate column to you main games table with all the tags up front so you don't need to join.  Then, you could simply add a trigger that whenever a tag is added or deleted from the game_tags_map table, it updates the main games table.  If this is for purposes of just display to a web-based game site, you are good.  If a person in interested in a game that is a certain type, then a query against the game_tags_map table would be good to summarize a list of that particular interest.

You are also doing a query of ALL games every time, so this may be the better avenue for you.

First, looking at your first query, and removing the ticks, 
quotes and aliasing your long table names to gtm and gt respectively,
your query never even USES the games_tags table as it is a left-join
and does not utilize any columns from it...

```
SELECT 
      gtm.game_id, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(gtm.tag_id) as tags
   FROM 
      games_tags_map gtm
         LEFT JOIN games_tags gt 
            on gtm.tag_id = gt.id
   GROUP BY 
      gtm.game_id
```

so in essence, it is doing nothing more than

```
SELECT 
      gtm.game_id, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(gtm.tag_id) as tags
   FROM 
      games_tags_map gtm
   GROUP BY 
      gtm.game_id
```

UNLESS, you intended to group_concat() to show the literal descriptions
that the IDs represented instead of the IDs themselves.  If by IDs, then
your second query could ALSO remove the inner left-join for games_tags table.

```
SELECT 
      g.id AS id,
      t.tags as tags
   FROM 
      games g
         LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
                          gtm.game_id, 
                          GROUP_CONCAT(gtm.tag_id) as tags
                       FROM 
                          games_tags_map gtm
                             LEFT JOIN games_tags 
                                on gtm.tag_id = gt.id
                       GROUP BY gtm.game_id ) t 
            ON g.id = t.game_id
```

In your last query, you are left-joining to actually get the TAG DESCRIPTIONS
instead of the tags.

```
SELECT 
      g.id,
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gt.tag) AS tags
   FROM 
      games g
         LEFT JOIN games_tags_map gtm 
            ON g.id = gtm.game_id
            LEFT JOIN games_tags gt
               ON gtm.tag_id = gt.id 
   WHERE 
      g.active = 1
   GROUP BY 
      g.id
```

To optimize this query, I would offer the following indexes..
This would make the entire query used with covering indexes and can process
the entire query by indexes and never need to go to the raw underlying data.

```
table           index
games           ( active, id )
games_tags_map  ( game_id, tag_id )
games_tags      ( id, tag )
```

One final note, when trying to offer more detail to posts, you can 
always EDIT your existing post, add more detail, then send comment to the user
regarding the additional data provided to review and possibly offer additional 
content / answer / response.

Comment: I am considering this route for additional reasons, but the question still stands, why are the 2 join queries significantly slower than they should be? I'm sure there must be a way to optimize them by tampering with the table structure.

Comment: @hedgehog90, see revision posting for clarification of your queries and covering indexes.

Comment: Thanks DRapp, very helpful post. What I ended up doing was to create several new columns on the games table such as '_tags' (I put an underscore prefix to remind me it's an automated field), which every time I add a new tag to gt or gtm, it also sets this column with all the tag literals. I avoid many joins and grouping this way, and it has made a massive difference in performance. Now I only need to refer to the gt and gtm tables when filtering games with speciific tags or when ranking similarity between games (with their tags and other data)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use index on foreign keys in the the tables ( `games_tags_map`.`tag_id`, `games_tags_map`.`game_id`) and the also index the column from which you trying to sort the query 
That will resolve your issue.

Comment: also add index on game.active . You can see if this works pretty run EXLAIN yourQuer . In the result can you see how it works. if you use more infos post the result from your query

Comment: I tried adding game_id and tag_id as separate indexes. Didn't improve when I tried both versions of the query. Can we focus on the first query that I mentioned took ~100ms? It has no 'order by', why is that so slow and how do I improve it?

Comment: First query is not the right way as you using a sub query in join which will work slow so why havent you used successive joins and used a sub query instead?
also if second query is giving you the expected results then adding index to the field you want to sort with will solve your issue.

Comment: ok, well considering the second query, I've tried adding the sort field as an index and it doesn't help matters.

Comment: Could you please give the output of run Explain your query?

Comment: Sorry, this will not be very readable. With 'WHERE active=1:
`id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra`
`SIMPLE | games | index | active | PRIMARY | 4 | NULL | 2462 | 75.02 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort`
`1 | SIMPLE | games_tags_map | ref | PRIMARY,game_id | PRIMARY | 4 | gpstudios_main.games.id | 2 | 100.00 | Using index`
`1 | SIMPLE | games_tags | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | gpstudios_main.games_tags_map.tag_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using where`

Comment: Without WHERE active=1 it's the same, except 'games' has key 'date_added' and key_len is '5'

Comment: How do I output the Explain in a text format that I can cleanly copy and paste? I'm using PHPMyAdmin